# Stream camera from iOS to Android

Tags: gratis, android, ios, streaming, camera

I want to use an iPhone (not jailbroken) as a camera and stream the live video to an Android (CyanogenMod) tablet.

Restrictions:

- This must work without Internet. The devices are in the same WLAN, and they are close enough to each other that Bluetooth would work.
- The video must not be saved (but an option for this is fine).
- The solution should ensure that only this specific tablet can receive the stream, not any eavesdroppers.
- All involved software must be gratis (ideally FLOSS in addition).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**iPCamera**](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ipcamera-high-end-network/id570912928?mt=8) on your iPhone, but the app is not gratis.

You can protect the access to the app by HTTP authentication. The username and password for this can be set up in the app preferences (in the settings).

After installation and running the app on your iPhone, open your browser in your Android device and type address which the iOS app gives to you.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, iPCamera does not appear to be gratis. Do you happen to know a gratis alternative? -- And about iPCamera: Do you know if it can use HTTPS? (seems to use HTTP by default)

Comment: Unfortunately there is no freeware alternative for iphone's iPCamera to use without additional software. so you can not use on android. see Epoccam [http://www.kinoni.com/index.html]